# Packer shell provisioners fails on custom ami

Tags: amazon-ec2, azure-devops, packer

Ive been running packer builds on a standard aws linux ami from azure devops. Ive just updated the packer.json to use a in-house hardened image instead and its starting failing on the shell provisioner with the error:

```
==> amazon-ebs: Provisioning with shell script: /home/vsts/work/1/s/packer/elasticsearch/scripts/setup.sh
==> amazon-ebs: Terminating the source AWS instance...
==> amazon-ebs: Cleaning up any extra volumes...
==> amazon-ebs: No volumes to clean up, skipping
==> amazon-ebs: Deleting temporary security group...
==> amazon-ebs: Deleting temporary keypair...
Build 'amazon-ebs' errored: Error uploading script: Process exited with status 1

==> Some builds didn't complete successfully and had errors:
--> amazon-ebs: Error uploading script: Process exited with status 1

==> Builds finished but no artifacts were created.
##[error]Error: /opt/hostedtoolcache/packer/1.4.3/x64/packer failed with return code: 1
```

Is this a bad error message and the error is elsewhere? I dont see how the upload could start failing when it worked before :X?

Comment: Rerun with env var PACKER_LOG=1